# Intellij issue with testng

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

I am facing issue while running testng tests in Intellij 2019.3.4 (Ultimate Edition)
[image: Error]

The tests run fine from commandline and eclipse. I did search the community but I couldn't find any help on the same.

Comment: Is the same issue reproduced when you run the test without the option: --illegal-access=permit or with another JDK version?

Comment: I haven't provided this option explicitly anywhere. JDK is 1.8

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of the Run configuration created for the test.

Comment: Please share actual code + error output as formatted text, rather than as screenshots. [This meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) explains the numerous reasons why this is important.